# An element command could not be completed because the element is not visible on the page

Tags: javascript, automation, webdriver-io

I am using webdriver.io to create an automatic test. I have a page with infinite scroll and i am trying to hit buttons as the page scroll down but after a time i receive the message: `An element command could not be completed because the element is not visible on the page.`

Here is my code which throws the error:

```
var scroll_value = 0;

$$('button[value="Undo"]').filter(function (link) {
   link.click().pause(1500);
   scroll_value += 100;
   browser.scroll(0, scroll_value);
});
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: I did not found a good solution. I tried with `setTimeout` with not luck. If you find the answer you can post it here. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to fix it by adding body to my selectors ex: `$("body #elem").click();` and using:

```
browser.execute(function() {
    document.getElementById('elem').scrollIntoView();
})
```